# Given real matrices $A,B$, exists $\tilde{B}$ so that $\langle Bx,x \rangle = \langle \tilde{B}x,x \rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

*Given $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, show there exists $\tilde{B}\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that*

1. $\langle Bx, x\rangle = \langle \tilde{B}x, x \rangle$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$
2. $\langle (A^2 + \tilde{B}^2) x,x\rangle \geq \langle (A\tilde{B} + \tilde{B}A)x, x\rangle$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

**My attempt so far:** Note that $(A-\tilde{B})^2$ positive semi-definite is sufficient for (2). For this it is sufficient that $A-\tilde{B}$ be symmetric.

Note that $B-\tilde{B}$ must have no eigenvalues in $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$.

Of course if $A,B$ symmetric, we can take $\tilde{B} := B$.

I'd like a hint for this one; please don't feed me the answer. Thanks as always, folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $B =B_{s}+B_{a}$ where $B_{a}$ and $ B_{a}$ are symmetric and antisymmetric parts. Then $\tilde{B} =B_{s}+X_{a}$ Where $X_{a}$ is any antisymmetric matrix. (This will take care of condition (1))

similarily $A =A_{s}+A_{a}$, then  condition (2) implies $(A_{s}-B_{s})^2+(A_{a}-X_{a})^2$ is positive definite. $(A_{s}-B_{s})^2$ is already positive definite while $(A_{a}-X_{a})^2$ is negative definite. Now you have to choose $X_{a}$ so that whole $(A_{s}-B_{s})^2+(A_{a}-X_{a})^2$ is positive definite.

Comment: $(A-\tilde{B})^2 = \left( (A_s + A_a) - (B_s + X_a) \right)^2 = (A_s - B_s)^2 + (A_a - X_a)^2 + 2(A_s - B_s)(A_a - X_a)$. Where has the last term gone? More specifically, how do you conclude that (2) $\Rightarrow (A_s - B_s)^2 + (A_a - X_a)^2 \geq 0$?

Comment: $(A-\tilde{B})^2$ is PD implies $(A-\tilde{B})^2+(A-\tilde{B})^{2T}$ is PD.

Comment: Very nice. -----

Comment: Recall that $(A_{a}-X_{a})^{T}=-(A_{a}-X_{a})$